# Labelling a stacked barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I created 2 variables, 1 to sort them into age groups and the other in order to find their percentages of the sample.

```
agegroup <- data$age
agegroup[data$age<20] <- 1
agegroup[20<=data$age & data$age<30] <- 2
agegroup[30<=data$age & data$age<40] <- 3
agegroup[40<=data$age] <- 4
agegroup1 <- table(agegroup)
percentages <- prop.table(agegroup1)
```

Afterwards, I've made a barplot to show the relationship between this and a second variable, ms

```
graph <- table(agegroup, ms)
barplot(graph, ylim = c(0,400), xlab = "ms", col = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green"))
legend("topright", title = "Age Group", legend = rownames(agegroup1), fill = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green"))
```

Which outputs something like this:

[image: barplot]

I'd like to add percentage labels to the graph but I'm unsure of how to (the percentage variable isn't helpful in this case, as it isn't conditional on ms), I've tried to use text(), but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you want the labels, you have a few options:

```
## basic barplot
tt <- table(mtcars$gear)
bp <- barplot(tt)
text(bp, tt, paste0(round(tt / sum(tt) * 100), '%'), pos = 3, xpd = NA)
```

[image]

```
## stacked barplot, top
tt <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$vs)
bp <- barplot(tt)
pt <- sprintf('%.f%%', prop.table(tt, margin = 1) * 100)
text(rep(bp, each = nrow(tt)), apply(tt, 2, cumsum),
     pt, xpd = NA, pos = 3)
```

[image]

```
## stacked barplot, bottom
tt <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$vs)
bp <- barplot(tt)
pt <- sprintf('%.f%%', prop.table(tt, margin = 1) * 100)
text(rep(bp, each = nrow(tt)), apply(tt, 2, function(x) head(c(0, cumsum(x)), -1)),
     pt, xpd = NA, pos = 3)
```

[image]

```
## stacked barplot, mid point
tt <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$vs)
bp <- barplot(tt)
pt <- sprintf('%.f%%', prop.table(tt, margin = 1) * 100)
text(rep(bp, each = nrow(tt)), apply(tt, 2, function(x) head(c(0, cumsum(x)), -1) + x / 2),
     pt, xpd = NA)
```

[image]

```
## stacked barplot, at x% height
tt <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$vs)
bp <- barplot(tt)
pt <- sprintf('%.f%%', prop.table(tt, margin = 1) * 100)
text(rep(bp, each = nrow(tt)), apply(tt, 2, function(x) head(c(0, cumsum(x)), -1) + x * 0.75),
     pt, xpd = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I've tried the options you've given me. Each of them give the same error where the margin doesn't match the dimensions of the table.
How should I proceed? Thanks.

Here's what the table 'agegroup' looks like: https://imgur.com/a/fiNNrSB

Comment: @TdZ that looks like a 1-d table, so the first example should work for that. your figure shows a 2-d table as in the other four toy examples. a 1-d table should only show four bars (not stacked)

Comment: Never mind, I shouldn't have been using the variable 'agegroup' for labelling, instead I should have used 'graph'. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Lastly, is there any way to avoid overlapping labels? https://imgur.com/a/DUmDvqA
The left box has 8% and 0% overlapping.